Can the US separation axiom be characterized by compact sets?
The separation axiom KC (Kompacts are Closed) implies the separation axiom US (Unique Sequential limits). In ‎sequential ‎space it was shown that, for sequential spaces, US is equivalent to all countably compact sets being closed. Is there a similar characterization that does not require the sequential assumption?

Yes, this characterization was observed by $\pi$-Base contributor @Jianing-Song:

US is equivalent to the property that every sequentially compact subset is sequentially closed.

where sequentially compact means every sequence has a subsequence converging within the set, and sequentially closed means all sequential limits are within the set.
Proof.  Suppose that $X$ is US. Let $C$ be a sequentially compact subset of $X$. If there was a sequence in $C$ converging outside of $C$, then by sequential compactness it would have a second limit within $C$, violating US. Thus $C$ is sequentially closed.
On the other hand, suppose $X$ is not US, so there is a sequence $x_n$ converging to two different points $a$ and $b$. It follows that every $\{x_n:N\leq n<\omega\}\cup\{a\}$ is sequentially compact, since every sequence either has an eventually constant subsequence, or else has a subsequence cofinal in $x_n$ and thus converging to $a$. Then we have two cases:

$x_n=b$ for infinitely-many $n$, then $\{b\}$ is sequentially compact but not sequentially closed as it misses the limit $a$.

$x_n\not= b$ for $n\geq N$, then $\{x_n:N\leq n<\omega\}\cup\{a\}$ is sequentially compact but not sequentially closed as it misses the limit $b$.



Finally, we note that the result of A‎ ‎sequential ‎space ‎has ‎unique ‎sequential ‎limits ‎iff ‎each ‎countably ‎compact ‎subset ‎is ‎closed. follows immediately: in a sequential space, countably compact and sequentially compact are equivalent, and closed and sequentially closed are equivalent.

The paragraph "On the other hand ..." seems a little shaky? Can you explain here why the last sentence holds?  And just to be clear, what do you mean by a trivial subsequence?

Trivial means eventually constant (and thus converges to that point). But I need to be more careful with the last sentence: maybe one of the x_n is b.

Exactly.  Need care about the $b$'s.
